# How to make mouseClicked work like mousePressed

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to make a menu, I want to trigger an event once the mouse has been pressed or clicked.

Currently when i press a button it triggers an event, however, I must keep pressing the mouse down otherwise it stops. I know there is a `mouseClicked()` function but I have been unsuccessful in implementing it into my code.

```java
Button[] buts; // creating new instance of array
PImage img;
StringList inventory;
String item;

color rectColor = 80;
color  rectHighlight = color(51);

color  baseColor = color(107);
color  currentColor = baseColor;

int  rectX = 50;
int  rectY = 50;
int awidth=277; int bheight=300;                                                  //  creating my own width and height because my build in func return incorrect numbers.
int rectSize1=awidth/2;
int rectSize2=bheight/8;
boolean rectOver = false;

void setup() {
    //  img = loadImage("Ranma.jpg");                   
    buts = new Button[4];                                                           // allocating space in array
    size(277, 300);
    inventory = new StringList("New Game","Load Game","Options","Exit");             // initializing the array with text for my buttons
    //initializeStars();

    for ( int i= 0; i<4;i++){                                                     // initializing buttons
      buts[i] = new Button(rectX, rectY+(rectSize2+10)*i, rectSize1, rectSize2, rectColor, baseColor,rectHighlight,currentColor, rectOver);  }
}

void draw() {
    //   image(img, 0, 0);
    background(255);    

    for (int i= 0; i<4;i++){
        buts[i].update(mouseX, mouseY);

        if (buts[i].rectOver && mousePressed){                          // I want to whenever the mouse is clicked on a button something happens, but not just while the mouse is pressed. 
          UIFUNC(i); }

        buts[i].hover();  }

    for (int i= 0; i<4;i++){                                       // text in in the end of loop, so showing ONTOP of squares instead of beneath. 
        item = inventory.get(i);  
        fill(255,0,0);
        textSize(16);
        text(item,rectX+awidth/10,rectY+(rectSize2+10)*i+30); }
}

class Button{

    int rectX, rectY;      // Position of square button

    int rectSize;     // Diameter of rect

    color rectColor,  baseColor;
    color rectHighlight;
    color currentColor;
    boolean rectOver;               // must be set to false 

    String  item;
    int rectSize1;
    int rectSize2;

    Button(int tempRectX, int tempRectY, int tempRectsize1,int tempRectsize2 ,color tempRectcolor, color tempBasecolor,color tempRecthighlight,color tempCurrentcolor, boolean tempRectover){
        rectX        =tempRectX;
        rectY        =tempRectY;
        rectSize1     =tempRectsize1;
        rectSize2     =tempRectsize2;
        rectColor    =tempRectcolor;
        baseColor    = tempBasecolor;
        rectHighlight= tempRecthighlight;
        currentColor = tempCurrentcolor;
        rectOver     =  tempRectover;
    }

    void update(int x, int y) {                               //if the mouse(for instance) is on the rectange/button then the boolean becomes true

        if ( rectOver(rectX, rectY, rectSize1, rectSize2) ) {
            rectOver = true;
        }
        else {
            rectOver  = false;}
    }

    boolean rectOver(int x, int y, int width1, int height1)  {    // is the mouse curser above the button 
        if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width1 && 
            mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+height1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void hover(){                                               // draws the buttons and highlights the buttons if mouse cursor is above. 

       if (rectOver) {
            fill(rectHighlight,125);
        } else {
            fill(rectColor,125);
        }
        stroke(255);

        rect(rectX, rectY, rectSize1, rectSize2);
    }
}

// my tempory and very bad attempt at making my buttons do stuff. 
int i;

void UIFUNC(int i){
 if (i==0){
     textSize(32);
     text("Loading a saved game",rectX,rectY);
   //  drawStars(); 
 }
  else if (i==1){     
     textSize(32);
     text("Loading a saved game",rectX,rectY);}

  else if (i==2){ 
     textSize(32);
     text("options",rectX,rectY);} 

  else if (i==3){ 
      exit(); 
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your time! 
Best Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to add a state variable (`clicked_button`), which states the index of the button which was clicked.
Set the sate in [`mouseClicked()`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseClicked_.html):

```java
int clicked_button = -1;

void mouseClicked() {
    for (int i= 0; i<4; i++) {
         if (buts[i].rectOver) {
             clicked_button = i;
         }
    }
}
```

Handle the button notification if the the variable is stated (`if (clicked_button >= 0)`) and reset the state (`clicked_button = -1;`) in `draw()`:

```java
void draw() {
    //   image(img, 0, 0);
    background(255);    

    for (int i= 0; i<4;i++){
        buts[i].update(mouseX, mouseY);
        buts[i].hover(); 
    }

    // I want to whenever the mouse is clicked on a button something happens,
    // but not just while the mouse is pressed. 
    if (clicked_button >= 0) {
        UIFUNC(clicked_button);
        clicked_button = -1;
    }

    for (int i= 0; i<4;i++){                                       
        item = inventory.get(i);  
        fill(255,0,0);
        textSize(16);
        text(item,rectX+awidth/10,rectY+(rectSize2+10)*i+30); }
}
```